# Changing a class from Select

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to append a class in a div via the values in the drop down. I've managed to do that, however, the previous class is still in the div and not getting replaced

so instead of getting

```
<div id="layoutblock" class="row one-column">
```

I'm getting

```
<div id="layoutblock" class="row one-column two-columns three-columns">
```

the classes are compounding

**The HTML**

```
<select id="layout">
<option value="one-column">one-column</option>
<option value="two-columns">two-column</option>
<option value="three-columns">three-column</option>
</select>

<div id="layoutblock" class="row"></div>
```

**The JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#layout").change(function () {
  var str = "";
$("#layout option:selected").each(function () {
  str += $(this).val();   
  });
$('#layoutblock').removeClass($(this) str);
$('#layoutblock').toggleClass(str);
})
.change();

</script>
```

Any ideas, Thanks

Regards
Said

Comment: Thanks Heaps guys, all solutions work nicely. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#layout").change(function () {
    $('#layoutblock')
        .removeClass()
        .addClass("row")
        .addClass($(this).val());
})
.change();
```

Comment: +1 Good soln. Note `$(this).val()` will give you the value of the selected option without the extra targeting.

Answer (score 1):

### [***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/tCWt7/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#layout").change(function () {
        $('#layoutblock')[0].className = "row " + $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
var oldVal = "";
$(function() {
    $("#layout").change(function () {
        if(oldVal) {
            $('#layoutblock').removeClass(oldVal);
        }
        $('#layoutblock').addClass($(this).val());
        oldVal = $(this).val(); //Update the old value   
    }).change(); 
 })
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hwznY/

Comment: This is the most flexible solution (It keeps any existing classes - in OP's case `row`) - and doesn't use `each()` (unnecessary in this case)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("select option:not(:selected)").each(function () {    
var value  = $(this).val();
$("#layout").removeClass(value);
 $("#layout").addClass($('#layout :selected').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to try

```
$("#layout").change(function () {
    $("#layoutblock").removeAttr("class");
    $("#layoutblock").attr("class", $("#layout option:selected").val()); 

    //Optional alert showing the new class of the div
    alert($("#layoutblock").attr("class"));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MvxLf/

Comment: it will remove all the classes